# PCNTL Installation Procedure

Tags: php, xmpp, pcntl

Im new to PHP and Socket Programming, Ive got an example script on sockets and when i run that it is thoring error  and asking to install  PCNTL extension but im not sure hot to install/add it to my server
Im using XAMPP in windows, can some one help me in this?

Comment: In the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php) it says: **Note:** Currently, this module will not function on non-Unix platforms (Windows).

So i think it isn't possible.